# Yet Another Simple Rebus

Tags: rebus

**Try to solve this simple rebus.**

[image]

It's too simple and hope will be answered within an hour or two. If not, will add hints. :)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Maybe it is:

> No one understands but you can

Because

> there is no "1" in the numbers, and that's under stands, and then a U made of cigarette butts, then a can.

Comment: Another possible ordering of the answer might be "no one understands but you can".

Comment: @IanMacDonald That seems to fit a bit better, thanks.  Will update.

Comment: Perfect. As I guessed, answered within a few minutes :)